# Reat out a file ion each machine with batch file issue

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, azure-batch

I have issue with my batch file. I want to find out a file on each different file and connect that file in my application

Here my script

```
#####################################################################################

IF NOT EXIST "c:\Program Files\ca\ca client\uninstall.exe" 
goto :eof
REM Remove the old ca client
REM Kill running programs, preventing uninstall
taskkill /im caf* /F
timeout 2
REM Backup the caf
rem rmdir "d:\FILE" /s /q
mkdir d:\FILE
copy "c:\Program Files\ca\ca client\setting*.caf" d:\FILE\
REM Use uninstaller to remove the client
cd\Program Files (x86)\ca\ca client\
Uninstall.exe /S

 REM Do folder cleanup - if not, refuse to install
 cd\
 rmdir "c:\ProgramFiles\ca\ca client\" /s /q
 SET go_Conn=go\Conn\scca
 IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" GOTO X86_PROG
 IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles\%go_Conn%" GOTO INSTALL
 exit /b 0
 :X86_PROG
 :INSTALL
 msiexec.exe /i "d:\goca.msi" /QN
 timeout 3
 Popd
 REM Start Gui - tray icon.
 start "" "C:\Program Files\ca\ca client\cagui.exe"
     cd C:\Program Files\ca\ca client\\
     casi.exe add -f "d:\FILE\cacode.caf" -n testconnect

:eof

END && EXIT

#########################################################################
```

here on that point

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\ca\ca client\cagui.exe"
     cd C:\Program Files\ca\ca client\\
     casi.exe add -f "d:\FILE\cacode.caf" -n testconnect
```

The file "cacode.caf" is called on each machine different.
in that line I add the file "cacode.caf" to my application

for example

on the "machine1" is called "cacode1.cf"
on the "machine2" is called "cacode2.cf"
on the "machine2" is called "cacode2.cf"

Is there any way to run the script on each machine and find the file *.caf and add the right config file on my application?

Regards

Comment: Is there only one on each machine?  You can do `for %%i in (D:\FILE\cacode*.caf) do ...`

Comment: I have 100 machines; the file extension is always .caf. Do you mean so, casi.exe add -f 
 for %%i in (d:\FILE\cacode*.caf) -n testconnect

Comment: What I asked was, does each machine have one file?  It would be `for %%i in (D:\FILE\cacode*.caf) do casi.exe add -f %%i -n testconnect`.

Comment: Yes only one file